# Override settings of Fancybox

Tags: fancybox-3

I'm my project i need to overwrite default setting for fancybox. Thumbnails `autostart` into `true`, like below. How I should do it.

```
thumbs : {
            autoStart   : true,   // Display thumbnails on opening
            hideOnClose : true     // Hide thumbnail grid when closing animation starts
        },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be best to override defaults using JS:

```
$.fancybox.defaults.thumbs.autoStart = true;
```